# How can I mimic "Colspan/Rowspan" using Divs as a alternative to Tables?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, html-table

I have been given a hard copy PDF file which is a form of clients to fill out. I need to re-create this form on a website. I am using Divs to mimic the functionality of a table, and I am really enjoying it so far (first time using divs > tables). The only issue I have run into is, I need to be able to do something similar to "Rowspan" Would love any help I can get!
Note: Rowspan is what I am having a hard time with, Colspan I got under control.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ and https://gridbyexample.com/examples/ to be able to span element through your grid layout ;) . if it  fails, set your html and css in your question , so one can help you .

Comment: Look into bootstrap layouts. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/